# How to do filter on Seq[Array[String]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, filter

I am trying to get the number files exists in the s3 bucket. I have list of paths as Seq which I am trying to check. I am trying to filter the paths and count but keep getting error.

```
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

files: Seq[String] = Vector(s3://dv-service-prod-na/output/sample/test/data/2016/12/01/*/*, s3://dv-service-prod-na/output/sample/test/data/2016/12/02/*/*, s3://dv-service-prod-na/output/sample/test/data/2016/12/03/*/*, s3://dv-service-prod-na/output/sample/test/data/2016/12/04/*/*, s3://dv-service-prod-na/output/sample/test/data/2016/12/05/*/*)

val filePath = files.map(x=> x.split("/\\*/\\*"))
val input = "s3n://dv-service-prod-na"
val missingPath = filePath.filter(x => (FileSystem.get(new URI(input), sc.hadoopConfiguration).exists(new Path(x))).equals(false)).count
```

Error :

```
console>:92: error: overloaded method constructor Path with alternatives: (x$1: java.net.URI)org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path <and> (x$1: String)org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path cannot be applied to (Array[String])
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Brian Expected output is supposed to be number of paths not exists.

Comment: @nmat Thanks ! That works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to flatten after the split:

```
val filePath = files.flatMap(x=> x.split("/\\*/\\*"))
```